# C# MySql Workbench Db with multiple dependencies DELETE query Parameters.AddWithValue? I know this is wrong I tried already multiple query types

Tags: c#, mysql

I need help with the query is connected to DGV and CellClick fullrow.  I need to execute query that will delete the selected row.

```
MySqlCommand cmd6 = con.CreateCommand(); connection to mysql workbench
                  
//query that is not working and I can't find any explanation how to do it.

cmd6.CommandText = "DELETE FROM customer WHERE customerId=@customerId(NULL auto-increment), customer=@customerName, customer=@addressId,customer=@active,customer=@createDate, customer=@createdBy, customer=@lastUpdate, customer=@lastUpdatedBy "; 
           cmd6.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customerName", textBox1Name.Text);//those are good and working just the query is not working.
           cmd6.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customerId", AddCustomerForm.SetValueForcustomerId);//working as well just the query
```

Answer (score 0):

The query changes to

```
DELETE FROM customer WHERE customerId=customerId;
```

This deletes the row entirely and the application works as designed.